# What is the meaning of this syntax exactly when finding the frequency of characters occuring in the string?

Tags: javascript, string, object

What is the meaning of this syntax exactly when finding the frequency of characters occuring in the string?

```
var str = 'abcccdddd';

function maxCharCount(target) {
    const chars = {};

    let maxChar = '';
    let maxValue = 1;

    for (let char of target) {
        chars[char] = chars[char] + 1 || 1; //what is the meaning of this line exactly in detail???
    }

    return chars;
}

console.log(maxCharCount(str));
```

Comment: assuming `chars` is an object, this code will go to the key `char` (ie a letter) and increment its associated `value` if the `key` `char` exsists. If it doesn't it will create a new `key` `value` pair and set the current character (`char`) as the key and it's associated value to `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full code and description:

```
function maxCharCount(target) {
    const chars = {};

    let maxChar = '';
    let maxValue = 1;

    for (let char of target) {
        chars[char] = chars[char] + 1 || 1;
    }

    return chars;
}

console.log(maxCharCount(str));
```

If `chars` is an object, the code will go to the property within `chars` named whatever `char` is equal to. If the property exists, it will be increments by 1. If it doesn't exist, it will be created and set to 1.

What the function itself does is it takes a string of characters, and returns an object containing character counts for each character in the string - so if we passed the string `hello`, the output should be:

```
{
    "h": 1,
    "e": 1,
    "l": 2,
     "o": 1
}
```

Comment: What does || means here? I know it is an or operator but what is the logic here?

Comment: It's an OR operator. What it does in this place is: if `chars[char]` exists, set it to itself plus one (so add one). If it doesn't exist, create it and set it to 1.

Answer (score 2):

`chars[char] + 1 || 1` has two sides: left and right. If left one resolves to falsy value, then the whole expression is resolved to the right side, and if the left resolves to truthy, the expression is resolved to the left side.

That said, the left side can only be falsy in one case: when `chars[char]` is `undefined` (when `chars` does not contain a property with name `char`). And `undefined + 1` gives `NaN` i.e. not a number, which is a falsy value.

Code like this should definitely be considered as bad, because it makes a developer's intention not obvious. Instead something at least like this should be preferred:

```
chars[char] = chars[char] ? chars[char] + 1 : 1;
```

Comment: This should be selected

Answer (score 1):

If char is in obj chars then it will + 1 it's count otherwise it will add char to object with value 1.